# Process.Start like a javascript popup without menu bars?

Tags: wpf

I am using Process.Start() to popup a webpage in my WPF app. This way it opens in my default browser.

In HTML/Javascript, you can do window popups and the window won't have menu bars, scrollbars, toolbars, etc. Is it possible to do this with Process.Start()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a `ChildWindow` (from the Extended Toolkit, or just another standard WPF `Window`) containing a `WebBrowser` object?

You will get easily rid of borders, scrollbars...any control except the page (and you can also stretch it easily in the window!)...

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpf.TestBrowser"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TestBrowser">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser Source="http://www.ribo.it/"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Width="300" Height="300" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

...and than show your browser window as usual:

```
TestBrowser window = new TestBrowser();
window.Show();
```